# How can i design star schema in pentahoo data integration

Tags: pentaho, data-warehouse, kettle, spoon

I have just started learning `PDI community` edition.

My main aim to create the `star schema` from normalized tables.

i was reading this tut

http://diethardsteiner.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/star-schema-modeling-with-pentaho-data.html

But in mt pentaho CE and i dont see any star schema option?

My Main aim is to get data from normalized tables and then insert into flattened tables with spoon kettle.

How can i go

Answer (score 1):

The star schema plugin is not available anymore as Pentaho have suspended the same.

You will have to develop your transformations manually. 
Try to create the transformation using the steps shown in the tutorial you shared.